# Python: Imported functions access to global variables

Tags: python, scope

I have two files as shown below.

```
#foobar.py

foo = False

def bar():
    if foo:
        print "Worked"
    else:
        print "Did not work"
```

and

```
#main.py

from foobar import *

foo = True
bar()
print foo
```

The output when I run `$ python main.py` is

```
Did not work
True
```

Is it possible for `bar()` to get access to the global `foo` defined in `main.py`?

**update**

Should have clarified earlier but I thought the question should remain as bare-bone as possible.

`foobar.py` is actually a supporting file (with other functions having different parameters that also use the global `foo`) that I want to use with a bunch of related iPython notebooks.

The notebooks should ideally have their own definitions of `foo` and it's absence should be caught and handled.

I chose to not include it as an argument simply to try and make the code look cleaner.

I am aware that:

> Wildcard imports ( from  import * ) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.-[pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: No, it's not. Why don't you want to use arguments?

Comment: Did you try to use `import foo` instead of `from foo import *`?

Comment: why are you declaring foo globally if you want to use foo from main.py?

Comment: I was simply trying out a code design. I now realize that it was poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting the comment by L3viathan as the answer.

> No, it's not. Why don't you want to use arguments? –  L3viathan Apr 22 at 19:15
>   [Python: Imported functions access to global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806831/python-imported-functions-access-to-global-variables#comment47741640_29806831)

Answer (score -1):

Change main.py to

```
#main.py

import foobar

foobar.foo = True
foobar.bar()
print foobar.foo
```

**OR**

change foobar.py to

```
#foobar.py
import __main__
foo = False

def bar():
    if __main__.foo:
        print "Worked"
    else:
        print "Did not work"
```

Well, the variable foo in main.py has scope to that module only, same goes for foobar.py. For further reading.

[how to access global variable within __main__ scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075140/how-to-access-global-variable-within-main-scope)